# Angular2: get validators limits

Tags: javascript, angular

For example I have such form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <input type="text" formControlName="username">
  <div ngxErrors="username">
    <div ngxError="required" [when]="['dirty', 'touched']">
      Username is required
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="text" formControlName="password">
  <div ngxErrors="password">
    <div ngxError="required" [when]="['dirty', 'touched']">
      Password is required
    </div>
    <div [ngxError]="['minlength', 'maxlength']" [when]="['dirty', 'touched']">
      5 characters minimum, 12 characters maximum
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

and this controller:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', [Validators.required]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(12)]]
    });
  }

}
```

How can I get my maxlength & minlength values? So that I can change:

`5 characters minimum, 12 characters maximum` like this:
`{{form.get('username').minlength}} characters minimum, {{form.get('username').maxlength}} characters maximum`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution. You can get the the minlength or the maxlength, but not both, from the error itself.

To get one or the other you can use syntax like this:

```html
<div ngxErrors="username" #myError="ngxErrors">
    <div ngxError="minlength" when="dirty">
        Min length should be {{ myError.getError('minlength')?.requiredLength }}
    </div>
</div>
```

but this is not completely what you want, because in the above case you have no way to access what the maxlength is when the minlength validator is giving you the error.
At first I thought it would be a simple matter to look up the validators from the form control. But apparently this is a feature that is not supported by angular yet: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13461

So the only possible solution at this point, I think, is to create your own custom validator that combines the minlength and maxlength validation, and sets both.

Here's how I did it. I created a custom validator in my validator service like this:

```js
static minAndMaxLengthValidator(options): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {
    [key: string]: any
  } => {
    if (
      control.value.length > options.maxLength ||
      control.value.length < options.minLength
    ) {
      return {
        minAndMaxLengthError: options
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I set the validator like this:

```js
    this.usernameOrEmail =
      new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        ValidationService.minAndMaxLengthValidator({
          minLength: 2,
          maxLength: 12,
      })]);
```

And then I can display the minLength and the maxLength simultaneously in my template (in this case using ngxErrors)

```html
    <md-input-container>
      <input
        mdInput 
        placeholder="Username or Email Address"
        formControlName="usernameOrEmail"
        required
      >
    </md-input-container>
    <div
      ngxErrors="usernameOrEmail"
      #usernameOrEmailError="ngxErrors"
    >
      <div
        ngxError="required"
        [when]="['dirty', 'touched']"
      >Username or Email Address is required</div>
      <div
        ngxError="minAndMaxLengthError"
        [when]="['dirty', 'touched']"
      >
        Username or Email Address must be min length
        {{
          usernameOrEmailError.getError('minAndMaxLengthError')?.minLength
        }}
        and max length
        {{
          usernameOrEmailError.getError('minAndMaxLengthError')?.maxLength
        }}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps!